# How to check more gently that some part of the code running 4 times a day

Tags: python, datetime

I have the script running by crontab and I want some part of the code being executed 4 times a day.

I have the snippet of code which

```
from datetime import datetime, time
now = datetime.now()
now_time = now.time()
if now_time == time(10,00) or now_time == time(16,00) or now_time == time(22,00) or now_time == time (4,00):
    func()
```

The minus of this solution is that this part of the code may be executed on 10.01, 10.02 and will be skipped this way.

Is there more gentle and shorter way to write down this part of code?

Thanks!

Comment: You need [corntab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), my friend.

Comment: @luoluo I'm already running this script by using crontab. If I'll use extention for crontab for python, will it hang the script in memory until the time come for crontab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is modify your script to accept an (extra) argument that will trigger the execution of that specific part of the code. You can then modify the crontab listing so that at the required times the script is called with that extra argument.

So, if you want to run the script every whole and half hour, and do the extra stuff at 4, 10, 16, and 22 o'clock, you can put the following three lines in your crontab file:

```
30 * * * * <script> # Thirty minutes after each hour
0 1-3,5-9,11-15,17-21,23 * * * <script> # Every whole hour, except the four designated hours
0 4,10,16,22 * * * <script with extra argument> # Script with extra argument at designated hours.
```

In this way, the script runs every 30 minutes, but at the designated hours the script runs with the extra argument.

Comment: Could you give me an example, because I don't know about conditionals in crontab. If I'll run both versions of code parallel, they'll block each other's access to sqlite3 database.

Comment: No conditionals. You would need entries with the extra argument for the times you want to execute the specific code. And entries without the extra argument for the other times that the script runs. How complex this will be depends on how often the script runs in total. But it has the advantage that you take the timing aspect out of the logic of the function. At the very least this makes it easier to test that the script does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: It runs every 30 minutes: */30 * * * * ~/env/bin/python2 ~/hasoffers_api/script.py > ~/hasoffers_api/logs/script_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.log 2>&1

Comment: Try: `30 * * * * <your script>` (every x:30 o'clock), `0 0-3,5-9,11-15,17-21,23 * * * <your script>` (every whole hour except the specific times), and `0 4,10,16,22 * * * <your script with extra argument>` to run the additional code.

Comment: But how to run once in half an hour in the second case? */30 0-3,5-9,11-15,17-21,23 * * * <myscript>?

Comment: Don't use the repeat syntax /30. That will run it every 30 minutes.

Comment: Don't use the repeat syntax `/30`. That will run it every 30 minutes, just like you already had, and that will cause the script to run two time simultaneously at some point. Instead, the first line I showed (`30 * * * * script`) will run the script 30 minutes after each hour. Don't use the repeat syntax, otherwise it will run it also every whole hour. The second line (`0 0-3,5-9,11-15,17-21,23 * * * script`) makes script run every whole hour, except 4, 10, 16, and 22 o'clock). The third line runs the script at those missing hours, with the extra argument. So no repeat syntax anywhere.

Comment: 30 minutes after each hour - it means once in hour. But I need to run it EVERY 30 MINUTES (it's the rate of the database update in my case) except hours when we pass an argument to the script. Here is the point.

Comment: That's what the other lines in the crontab file are for.

Comment: But why can't we make it simplier: */30 0-3,5-9,11-15,17-21,23 * * * script without argument. 0 4,10,16,22 * * * script with argument. There is no intersections.

Comment: You probably could. But I am never comfortable with mixing ranges and repeats on one crontab file line -- I never can faithfully deduce when execution happens and when not. With three separate line, in my eyes at least, there is no question about what happens. And it is not if an extra crontab line is costly or so. So, my advice is to go for clarity, not for a minimal number of crontab file lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the flexibility to move to APScheduler (http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html) your job becomes easier and the code is more reliable.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

# assuming tick is your function
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
#cron which runs once in 6 hours
scheduler.add_job(tick, 'cron', hour='*/6')
scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to solve the problem.

1) Use the global variable as a counter

```
numOfCalls = 0
#for every func() call
func()
numOfCalls = numOfCalls + 1
```

2) Every time function is executed, time stamp and func name might be written to some log file

```
from datetime import datetime, time
current_time = datetime.now().time()

with open("log.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("func " + str(current_time) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are after are time intervals. From the same package `datetime` you can create `timedelta` objects (difference between two datetimes) and cast them to seconds

Your code becomes:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
now = datetime.now()
today = now.date()
minutes_accepted = 5
execution_times = [time(hour=10), time(hour=16), time(hour=22)]
for delta in [datetime.combine(today, et) - now for et in execution_times]:
    if abs(delta.total_seconds()) < minutes_accepted * 60:
        print 'func'
```